# How can I decide what files will be installed when I write a homebrew formula?

Tags: homebrew

I'm trying to write a brew formula(for example, `foo`) but need to save some files in `/usr/local/Cellar/foo/1.0.0/` such as `VERSION`, but I find that brew only save some files in that dir such as `README`, `LICENSE` and so on.

So.. how can I change the default behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find this can be implemented by add `prefix.install 'VERSION'` to install method of your formula class.